# Javascript/jQuery Popup Loop and Add

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly, I am quite new to programming, so please be gentle. Stack Overflow has been a wonderful resource for me, so thankyou to all of you contributors.

This one I cannot crack though, and it's a difficult search item, as you can probably tell by the cryptic title...

Anyway, I have a jQuery popup function which gets called from a events.register control. Essentially whenever a user clicks in the map it sends a request to a web service, gets the data back, populates a form which the user can then interact with and save data back to SQL.

It works really well I am happy with its progress.

One of the functions is to change the value in a table, I want the user to get a prompt to ensure they don't accidentally save something they don't intend. It works perfectly the first time after a refresh, but then each time after that it adds one confirm, then again, until eventually after the fifth time there are 5 confirms that appear one after the other. Once the user clicks through them the code runs fine and I get expected results.

I only call the confirm once (I think?) but, yeah, I am lost, here is my function, sorry if it is hard to read or poorly formatted:

```
function popup() {
        j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function() {
            //open popup
            j("#detailsform").height(250);
            j("#detailsform").fadeIn(1000);
            positionPopup();
            document.getElementById("condition").value = getCondition;
            j("#selCatHead").hide();
            j("#cats").hide();
            //dispose tree
            j("#dispose").click(function() {
                if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    disposetree();
                }
                else { return false; };
            });
            //save defect
            j("#savedef").click(function() {
                saveDef();
            });
            //fade in defects
            j("#adddefect").click(function() {
                j("#detailsform").height(400);
                j("#selCatHead").fadeIn(1000);
                j("#cats").fadeIn(1000);
            });
            //fade out popup
            j("#close").click(function() {
                j("#detailsform").fadeOut(500);
            });
        });          // close document ready function

        //position the popup at the center of the page
        function positionPopup() {
            if (!j("#detailsform").is(':visible')) {
                return;
            }
            j("#detailsform").css({
                left: (j(window).width() - j('#detailsform').width()) / 2,
                top: (j(window).width() - j('#detailsform').width()) / 7,
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        } // close positionPopup function

        //maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
        j(window).bind('resize', positionPopup);

    }; // close popup function
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @jfriend00, removed function from popup call and turned off handler each time, eg:

```
function popup() {
        j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function() {
            //open popup
            j("#detailsform").height(250);
            j("#detailsform").fadeIn(1000);
            //dispose
            j("#dispose").off();
            j("#dispose").click(function() {
                disposeClickHandle();
            });
            //save
            j("#savedef").off();
            j("#savedef").click(function() {
                saveDef();
            });
        });
```

and then:

```
function disposeClickHandle() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            disposetree();
        }
        else { return false; };
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only install a click handler ONCE.  If you install it multiple times, it will trigger multiple times.

So, everytime you call your `popup()` function it installs yet another click handler.  And, then when you click, the click handler will trigger multiple times.  You should either move your click handler installation outside the function that you call multiple times and put it in an initialization function that is only called once at the beginning OR you can remove the click handlers after your operation so when you install it again, it will only be installed one time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jfriend00! Appreciate the time.

Do you mean only one .click(function() per element within the popup? Or only one total for the whole function?

If so, what is a way to trigger the other functions based on when the user clicks on an element?

Thanks again!

Comment: Think I got it, I'll give it a crack and revert back.

Comment: @MorganEllingham - only call `.click(fn)` once for each element.  If you call it more than once, then it will call your callback function more than once when things are clicked.

Comment: Thanks again @jfriend00.

I kind of did both of your suggestions, removed the function to outside of the popup call and turned off the click function before installing it each time using http://api.jquery.com/off/

I hope this is right! It works well now.